# Most optimal way to add text to an element with an ID?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following ID's and wish to add the Special Characters `&times, &#10094, &#10095` with CSS or JavaScript instead of writing it manually on every page in the html document.

```html
<div id="lightbox">
    <a id="lightbox-close">&times;</a>
    <a id="lightbox-prev-img">&#10094;</a>
    <a id="lightbox-next-img">&#10095;</a>
</div>
```

Would it be recommended to do that through CSS, like so:

```
.lightbox-close:before {
   content: "&times";
}
```

Or through JavaScript, like so:

```js
var lightboxClose = document.getElementById("lightbox-close");
var text = document.createTextNode("&times");

lightboxClose.appendChild(text);
```

Comment: or option 3: `document.getElementById("lightbox-close").innerHTML='&time';` eighter way, if possible it's still better to do it in HTML. This might not be search engine relevant content. But if it is somewhen then prerendered HTML is still the way to go

Comment: @caramba So essentially, if it contains important information, keep it in the HTML document. Otherwise use any of the listed methods (including yours) to write the code for you?

Comment: @HereticMonkey it sort of does, but it doesn't mention the CSS variation. I am keen to know which of the ways is the most preferable.

Comment: "Most preferable" is an opinion, which is not on topic on Stack Overflow. You've also accepted an answer which doesn't mention the CSS variation, so the answers are identical.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: "... instead of writing it manually on every page in the html document." Seems like you just want to avoid having to maintain identical HTML content across multiple HTML files. So far, only client-side techniques have been discussed. I would strongly consider doing it instead in your build/deployment pipeline (templating) or on the webserver (server-side scripting).

Comment: @RuudHelderman That is true, server-sided scripting would be the best approach to my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend to use innerHTML to change text. Instead use innerText or textContent.

```js
let value = "something";

lightboxClose.textContent = `&${value}`;
```

Comment: I actually don't want to change the text. I wish to remove the text in the HTML document so that there is no text and then add that through CSS or JS. How come innerHTML is frowned upon?

Comment: If the elements have html children elements it will remove the elements and replace it with text instead of only adding text to the element.

You can just make it into an empty string like this ```lightboxClose.textContent = ""```
```lightboxClose.textContent = "something"``` will replace the old text with new text

Comment: Thank you Henrik, this answer solved my issues. Meanwhile I wait to accept your answer (Timer before I can accept answer). Would you use your method to solve my issue? Is this more recommended over CSS?

Comment: I would use javascript, but it depends on the usage. If you know that this is the only functionality that you need and it's possible through CSS then use css since you're probably more familiar with CSS. But learning Javascript will make many more possibilties open up for you :)

Comment: Thank you Henrik, have a great day! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var lightboxClose = document.getElementById("lightbox-close");
lightboxClose.textContent = `&${value}`;
```

The easiest way to do it. I just took above answer and modified it by adding the selector.

Comment: Thanks for this variation, I appreciate it!